# Contineous cast std::any

Tags: c++, foreach, c++17, tuple

Хочу написать вспомогательный шаблонный метод, который пробует скастовать std::any к нескольким типам. Метод должен работать с tuple потому что я, на самом деле, еще сортирую tuple для каста к оптимальному типу по размеру, оптимальные типы начинаются с головы. Сейчас мне нужно перебрать tuple, но именно по типам, а не по значениям. В сети везде примеры только с иницированным туплом и работой со значениями. Мне же нужно перебрать именно типы. Пока я сам так не умею :)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto contineous_cast(std::any any) {
    std::tuple<Ts...> tuple;
    // algorithm :
    // forEach tuple T
    // std::optional<tuple current T> opt = std::any_cast<tuple current T>(any);
    // if (opt has value) return opt value;
}
```

Использую optional потому что с ним можно избежать исключений и проверять удачный каст через указатель. Вернуться должно именно значение скастованное к подошедшему типу.

Update, вот некоторый прогресс, научился доставать типы из тупла, осталось перебрать его циклом.

```
/* Get tuple type */
template <int N, typename... Ts>
struct get_tuple_type;

template <int N, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get_tuple_type<N, std::tuple<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = typename get_tuple_type<N - 1, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get_tuple_type<0, std::tuple<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
auto contineous_cast(std::any any) {

    using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    std::size_t length = sizeof...(Ts);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        using type = proccessor::utilities::get_tuple_type<i, tuple>::type; 
        // ругается на i
        std::optional<type> opt = get_optional_value<type>(any);
        if (opt.has_value()) {
            return *opt;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возвращаемый тип должен быть известен во время компиляции. Единственный вариант - вернуть `std::variant<Ts...>`. Вам такое подойдет?

Comment: Думаю да. Можно разбить задачу на два этапа, сначала просто вытащить значение и скастовать его к варианту или к к common type а потом уже попробовать скастовать common type к оптимальному типа из списка. Я думаю справлюсь с этим. Не понимаю именно как перебрать типы в тупле.

Comment: Тип по индексу выдает `std::tuple_element`, но я думаю проще без этого. См. ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Именно цикл по типам делается совсем просто:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void foo()
{
    ([&]{
        // Код здесь выполяется для каждого типа из `Ts...`.
        std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << '\n';
    }(), ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, float, double>();
}
```

---

Если вам нужно дополнительно знать индекс типа (как константу времени компиляции), тогда чуть сложнее:

```
template <typename Integer, Integer ...I, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for_each(std::integer_sequence<Integer, I...>, F &&func)
{
    (func(std::integral_constant<Integer, I>{}) , ...);
}

template <auto N, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for(F &&func)
{
    if constexpr (N > 0)
        constexpr_for_each(std::make_integer_sequence<decltype(N), N>{}, std::forward<F>(func));
}
```

А потом вот так:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
void foo()
{
    using tuple_t = std::tuple<Ts...>;

    constexpr_for<std::tuple_size_v<tuple_t>>([&](auto index)
    {
        constexpr auto i = index.value;
        std::cout << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<i, tuple_t>).name() << '\n';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Опираясь на constexpr_for @HolyBlackCat получилось в итоге так:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto contineous_cast(std::any any) -> std::common_type_t<Ts...> {

    using tuple_t = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using common_t = std::common_type_t<Ts...>;
    common_t value = 0;

    constexpr_for<std::tuple_size_v<tuple_t>>([&](auto index) {
        constexpr auto i = index.value;
        using optional_t = std::tuple_element_t<i, tuple_t>;
        std::optional<optional_t> optValue = get_optional_value<optional_t>(any);
        if (optValue) { value = *optValue; };
    });

    return value;
}
```